# EventListener is not work

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>I need Help</title>
    <style media="screen">
    .try {
        padding: 3em;
        background: #B51C35;
        text-align: center;}
    .try a {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 0 .5em;
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #FFFCED;
        text-decoration: none;
        border: 5px solid #FFFCED;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="">
      <h3 style="text-align:center;">The event in the console was worked but remove Attribute is not work!! <br />I just need the advice or if you can told me why is not working? </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="try movemaus">
      <a href="#">Book Now!</a>
    </div><!-- .cta -->

    <script>
      const NEWSTYLE = document.querySelector(".movemaus");
      NEWSTYLE.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){NEWSTYLE.removeAttribute(".try");}, false);
      NEWSTYLE.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){console.log("The Function is work in the Console");}, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Dear All, 
The event in the console was worked but remove Attribute is not work!! 
I just need the advice or if you can told me why is not working?
Thanks in Advance,
Mustafa

Comment: `removeAttribute` does what the name says, it removes actual _attributes_ from elements. There is no attribute named `.try` on any element. If you want to remove this single _class_ from an element … then go do some research, please, how that is done properly.

Comment: Thx for replay and advice for search!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event does work, but the approach to removing a class from an element is incorrect. Instead of `removeAttribute`, you could use `element.classList.remove(className)` to remove the class.

```js
const NEWSTYLE = document.querySelector(".movemaus");
NEWSTYLE.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  NEWSTYLE.classList.remove("try");
}, false);
NEWSTYLE.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
  console.log("The Function is work in the Console");
}, false);
```

```css
.try {
  padding: 3em;
  background: #B51C35;
  text-align: center;
}

.try a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #FFFCED;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 5px solid #FFFCED;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">The event in the console was worked but remove Attribute is not work!! <br />I just need the advice or if you can told me why is not working? </h3>
</div>
<div class="try movemaus">
  <a href="#">Book Now!</a>
</div>
<!-- .cta -->
```

Comment: Hello Nisarg, 
Thanks alot for the great support and the quick response.
I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I try not to understand it good, to avoid the copy Paste from another developer.
Thanks again, wish you a nice day.
Mustafa

Answer (score 1):

`removeAttribute` removes the **named attribute**. The value you pass it should be an attribute name (like `"class"`) and not a CSS selector (like `.try`).

If you want to remove a class from the element, then you should use [the `classList` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).

```
NEWSTYLE.classList.remove("try");
```

Comment: Dear Quentin,
Many thanks to wonderful explain.
Wish you a nice day.
Mustafa

Answer (score -1):

`.try` is a css class, not an attribute. You could remove the `class` attribute completely with `removeAttribute`, but not a single class out of the value. For this task you could use `classList`.

And why not combine the event listeners?!

```js
document.querySelector(".movemaus").addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
  e.target.classList.remove("try");
  console.log("The Function is work in the Console");
});
```

```css
.try {
  padding: 3em;
  background: #B51C35;
  text-align: center;
}

.try a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #FFFCED;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 5px solid #FFFCED;
}
```

```html
<div class="">
  <h3 style="text-align:center;">The event in the console was worked but remove Attribute is not work!! <br />I just need the advice or if you can told me why is not working? </h3>
</div>
<div class="try movemaus">
  <a href="#">Book Now!</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Eisbehr,
Many thanks for the explain.
I will try that now with the .toggle :)
Thanks again.
Mustafa

Comment: Hi again, 
I didn't knew that I can combine it, when I read your modification agine I understand your point of view.
am a beginner in JS and I like coding, but now I find it complicated but I thing it will come.
I just need to know according to your experience in this website: my question is normal or this website just for the professional ?
Thanks for your time and wish you a nice day.
Mustafa

Comment: I think I don't understand your question?! @MustafaAlAwad

Comment: my post or my question for the event not work that normal question or this website for the propositional coder more than the beginner.

Comment: SO is for both, beginner and pros. But to be honest, you should not use comments for ask things like this. Use https://meta.stackoverflow.com for such questions.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice.
you know we must ask to know where is the right platform to ask in it.